# Unable to parse JSON using JObject.Parse()

Tags: c#, json

Every time I try to parse JSON I get this exception:

```
    Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json, JsonLoadSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json)
   at ai.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/asdf/RiderProjects/ai/ai/Program.cs:line 19
```

Some of my code

```
url2 = "img"; 
var client = new RestClient("example.org?url=" + url2);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
dynamic epic = JObject.Parse(response.Content);

string stuff = epic.stuff;

Console.WriteLine(stuff);
```

Comment: Have you debugged and checked what is in response.Content?

Comment: What contains the `response.Content` variable. Check if it has a valid json format.

Comment: i have checked and it is valid json ```[{"faceId":"d9828616-b702-4f9b-9d7b-30eb3f0705e4","faceRectangle":{"top":26,"left":71,"width":321,"height":321},"faceAttributes":{"smile":0.007,"headPose":{"pitch":-9.8,"roll":4.6,"yaw":26.6},"gender":"female","age":22.0,"facialHair":{"moustache":0.0,"beard":0.0,"sideburns":0.0},"glasses":"ReadingGlasses","emotion":{"anger":0.001,"contempt":0.0,"disgust":0.001,"fear":0.058,"happiness":0.007,"neutral":0.25,"sadness":0.032,"surprise":0.651}}}]```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not a `JObject`, that is a `JArray`, you can tell by the square bracket around the entire response.  You'll need to fix that before anything.

`JArray arr = JArray.Parse(response.Content);`

See my dotnetfiddle with your exact object: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PGZcay